# Z_buffer, where to find it and how to use it?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, camera, source-code

I'm trying to implement some function in blender for an university essay but I'm stuck.

I need the z_buffer of the rendering camera in cycles to find the distance between every pixel of the render and the object falling in its frustum.

Where can i find it?

I'm looking for a `'something.h'` file if possible.

Comment: I found this: 
`source/blender/draw/engines/workbench/workbench_effect_dof.c`
i think it is somehow linked to z buffer, but I can't  understand how: may anybody explain?

Comment: I don't think we have many experts on the c or c++ side of Blender here, You might have better luck there https://devtalk.blender.org/

Comment: Thank you! If anybody might be interested this is the devtalk link:
https://devtalk.blender.org/t/z-buffer-how-can-i-find-distance-between-render-pixel-and-scene-object/16950